# can we pass the address of the format specifier string to printf

Tags: c, pointers, char, printf

how can we write such type of syntax

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  char *str;
  str="%s";
  printf(str,"K\n");
  return 0;
}
```

is the `printf` statement valid?

Comment: Stop. Close your browser. Pick up a copy of [K&R](http://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/dp/0131103628), [Practical C programming](http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Programming-3rd-Steve-Oualline/dp/1565923065/), and/or [Head First C](http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-C-David-Griffiths/dp/1449399916/). **Read**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is valid, since your `str` is of type `char *`. This is the prototype of printf:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

From the view of the called function, your statement will be the same as:

```
printf("%s","K\n");
```

With `"%s"` and `"K\n"` being a constant expressions of the type `char *`.

Comment: You are saying that the `printf` call is invalid because he does not specify a return type in main?

Answer (score 3):

The function call to `printf()` is valid, because as its first parameter, it expects a constant string serving as the format specifier. Don't think about a string being stuff placed between quotes - think of it as an array of characters (plus a terminating 0 character). In C (and in any programming language that makes sense) as long as there's a value, its type and actual value/contents determine its behavior - let it be a literal, a variable or any other expression (let's not consider const correctness for now for tha sake of simplicity). Like in maths, it doesn't matter whether you write

```
3 + 2 = 5
```

or

```
x = 3
y = 2
x + y = 5
```

here the third line of the second equality is still valid despite x and y not being literals. They're variables, and their current value is used when working with them.

Now a minor point about const correctness that the other answers lack: a string literal is of type `const char *` and not `char *` since you can't change its contents. Therefore it's not really good to write

```
char *foo = "blah blah";
```

write instead

```
const char *foo = "blah blah";
```

Comment: Well string literals are of type `char[]`, unfortunately (not pointers and not `const`). Also you missed the invalid specification of `main`.

Comment: @JensGustedt what? Not const? I always thought it was const. Btw isn't that indifferent whether it is an array or a pointer? It's only one-dimensional and I don't want to assign anything to a string literal, so practically it can be used as a pointer. And modofying its contents **is** undefined behavior, so it must be const...

Comment: No, not `const` :( And exactly it is UB. If the type would be `const` qualified it would be a constraint violation and force a diagnostic. Then, no a pointer and an array are not the same thing. A string literal has size information `sizeof "ha"` is 3.

Comment: @JensGustedt yes, I know arrays are not pointers. I meant to say they behave the same here. (I know there's a difference in sizeof, but that's irrelevant to the question of const correctness.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the syntax is valid. The result of this program is the string "K\n"

Where \n means newline.

The %s tells printf that the first arg it will be printing should be printed as a string.

See this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

This is a very simple program. In the time it took you to ask this question, you could have compiled and run the program yourself and seen the answer. You learn best by doing.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s","K\n");` - This statement two string literals `%s` ans `k\n`. These two string literals will be in text segement as a read only data. Now consider `1000` is the address of the string literal `%s` and `2000` is the address of the string literal `k\n`. `1000` and `2000` will be the two arguements, which will be passed to the `printf`.

```
printf("%s","K\n");
```

this can be written as below way also

```
...
char *a = "%s";  //Address 1000 is stored in a
char *b = "k\n"; //Address 2000 is stored in b
printf(a,b);     //Now we are passing 1000 and 2000 to printf
...
```

And also I want to tell you that the below method also can print a string.

```
...
char *a = "hello world"
printf(a); //This will print hello world
...
```